# OpenGL ES 2.0 Initialization under iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, initialization, opengl-es-2.0

I've been working on my own game for a while now and it works fine on windows. Everything is designed to have support for cross platform. In order for you to understand my question I'll have to explain a bit how everything works:

There are multiple libraries: Platform, Video, XML, Image and Engine. Each of these compile as a DLL under windows or as a static library on iOS.

Everything in the libraries is either a normal function (declared with `extern "C"`) or a object which has a interface.

The folder structure is organized like this: Project, Include, Source.

In the include folder there is only common code for all platforms like interfaces and function prototypes. In the source folder there are other folders specific for each platform.

I managed to port the Platform library on iOS without any problems but now I'm stuck on the Video one.

This handles the rendering API (OpenGL under windows and Opengl-ES 2 under iOS).

To create a driver I have to use the following function:

```
IVideoDriver* CreateVideoDriver(void* container)
```

Container is a `HWND` under windows.

The thing is that I'm not sure about how to use this initialization style under iOS.

I've read some tutorials, looked at sample source code but I can't figure out how to do this. From what I see the OpenGL initialization must be done in a view and I don't know how to link all that with my code. I know  I have to use some objective-c code but that's not a problem.

Could anyone please help me out with this problem?

Comment: I would recommend to look at cocos2d-x engine. It is cross-platform, uses OpenGL ES and has a nice code structure. As for video - if it is full-screen movie than the better way would be to use native iOS player `MPMoviePlayerController` (it's hardware accelerated).

Comment: I inspected multiple engines but I think somehow I skipped over cocos2d-x. The video library is the one which takes care of low lever rendering features (setting attribute streams, binding textures, rendering arrays of indices, etc). I don't have any plans for movie playbacks at the moment. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **EAGLView** and **ESRenderer** provided in many iOS samples (see [GLEssentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLEssentials) or [GLES2Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLES2Sample)).

It is quite simple to use. Just don't forget link with the OGLES framework, and you'r done!

Your VideoDriverIOS will look like :

In a VideoDriverIOS.h/VideoDriverIOS.mm

```
class VideoDriverIOS : public IVideoDriver
{
public:
    ...
    // implement the pure virual here
protected:
    EAGLView* mView;
    ...
}
```

and your methods can directly use the mView object.

Comment: I like this. It sounds like it could work. I haven't had time to test it but now that the weekend is coming I will. If I understood well then mView will be passed from CreateVideoDriver right? That way some initialization could be done outside, the rendering will still work perfectly and EAGLView is a pretty standard class.

Comment: I would say yes. In your viewController.mm, the [viewDidLoad] would instantiate the EAGLView, call your_lib->createVideoDriver with the EAGLView ptr. Cast the IVideoDriver result in VideoDriverIOS to perform some platform specific operations. This is only a blind guess, but as far as I understood, it could fit in your project.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5.0, Apple introduced the GLKit View, which provides the default implementation of an OpenGL ES-aware view. You can also use the GLKit View Controller which manages the GLKit View. These are objects you can drag right into your main .xib via XCode and hook them up seamlessly to your implementation.

Ray Wenderlich wrote an excellent starter post, it might help you with hooking it all up.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1

Good luck!